# Clarification regarding functioning of getchar()/putchar()

Tags: c

In this code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int i,p=0;
    while(i!=EOF)
    {
            i=getchar();
            putchar(i);
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

When I enter *hello* as input in one go, the output is **h** then in the next line **e** and so on. But when **h** is printed then before printing **e** why `getchar()` doesn't take pause to take input from me just like it did in the first time?

`getchar()` *returns* either any successfully read character from **stdin** or some error, so which function is demanding terminal input and then sending it to **stdin**?

Comment: Initially what `i` contains ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not waiting? What happens if you enter "h" then wait a moment, then "e" etc?

Comment: `getchar()` just return next character from `stdin` stream (or `EOF` on the end of stream or error). So, it will wait when stream is empty.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Nope, it (putchar(i)) goes on printing values.

Comment: You should consider rewriting this as a `do`/`while` loop instead of a `while` loop. As written, `i` will initially contain a random value, and while it isn't likely to happen terribly often, it's technically possible that `i` could happen to start as `EOF`, short-circuiting your entire loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input from a terminal is generally *buffered*. This means it is held in memory waiting for your program to read it.

This buffer is performed by multiple pieces of software. The software that is actually reading your input in the terminal window generally accumulates characters you type until you press enter or press certain other keys or combinations that end the current input. Then the line that has been read is made available to your program.

Inside your program, the C standard library, of which `getchar` is a part, reads the data that has been sent to it and holds it in a buffer of its own. The `getchar` routine reads the next character from this buffer. (If the buffer is empty when `getchar` wants another character, `getchar` will block, waiting for new data to arrive from the terminal software.)

Comment: So, when there is nothing in the buffer getchar() takes the terminal data until some delimiter is entered and then pushes the data to the stdin - when getchar() finds that buffer is not empty, it starts returning characters one by one from buffer until there is some error or buffer is empty? When the buffer becomes empty, getchar() again demands data?

So, getchar has dual function.

Comment: @infinite: There are multiple layers of software involved, some of which are not inside your process. This depends on the system you are running on, but, typically, when you call `getchar`, the standard library checks its buffer. If that buffer is empty, it calls a system routine like `read` to get more data from the stream. That system routine generates a request to the operating system, so your process stops running while the system works on it. The system essentially forwards the request to software involved in the terminal operation.…

Comment: … That software might have more data available (although, for short lines, it probably sent it all in one group). If it does not, then it waits for the user to type more. There is various software managing the interface to the user. When the user types some characters and presses enter, the new data goes to through the terminal input software, to the operating system, to your process, to the standard library I/O routines, and then to `getchar`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the loop condition.  You are continuing to loop until EOF is received.  When you type "hello", it works exactly as you expect except STDIN has more characters in the buffer and none of them are EOF.  The program prints out "h", then a newline, and goes back to check the loop condition.  EOF has not been found, so then it gets the next character from STDIN (which you have already provided) and the cycle repeats.

If you remove the loop it will only print one character.

Comment: The question does not ask why multiple characters are printed. It asks why calls to `getchar` do not wait for the user to enter new input.